# Am I eligible for unemployment? Resigned, transitioned to part time, then let go

Tags: maryland, unemployment

Work was too much, too many hours, no life, inability to take care too much stress so...

I discussed resigning with my boss early January, and was convinced to stay with some help offered to reduce work load.

That didn't work, so I submitted resignation letter w/2 weeks notice - last day March 13th. I cited the reasons above, said I'd be resigning, but also offered to stay on 6 hours/day.

Two days before March 13th, we agreed to convert me to half time employee. So now I'm exempt, working 20 hours/week (no time sheets), and they cut my salary in half. We have nothing in writing on the agreement, but I have email from my boss discussing 1/2 time & cutting pay in half and he also says they "stopped the official termination". At the time we did trade some instant messages regarding how we could do this until either side got tired of it.

Now they're letting me go July 1st. Seems to me, since I like the arrangement and would love for it to continue - that they are now terminating me and i should be eligible for unemployment.

Am I correct? Do I need to get anything in writing from my employer to prove they let me go?  Right now all I have is my boss verbally telling me they have no money in the budget for me starting new fiscal year (July 1st).

Some research below from Maryland unemployment page.

Thanks so much for your time and feedback!

From example scenarios MD lists on their unemployment Q&A page:

The claimant wrote a letter of resignation effective February 12, 1988. Following this, the employer repeatedly asked the claimant to continue her employment. The claimant then agreed to stay on indefinitely. The claimant continued to work through March 18, 1988, at which time the employer told the claimant that it was accepting her resignation. The claimant, at the employer's request, clearly engaged in a course of action that indicated that her resignation was rescinded. Therefore, her failure to physically retrieve her resignation letter cannot be used by the employer to change her layoff into a resignation. Chambers v. Buffalo Tank Corporation of Delaware, 743-BR-88.

Answer (score 0):

Eligibility for unemployment will be governed by Maryland standards, but generally involves how many hours you have worked in the past 12 months.  Specifics are found on the MD Dept of Labor website.  This is because employers pay into the unemployment fund for every hour you work.  So in general if you worked less than 2000 hours in the past year your benefits will be reduced by the fraction of hours out of 2000 that you worked (in an unemployment-eligible position).  The reality is much much more complicated, designed of course by the government to be complex.

Comment: Full time for many years through mid-March, then 1/2 time to present.  I'm really looking for a read on the technicality that I resigned, we worked out a 1/2 time gig, now they're saying I need to go.  If that counts as a resignation, then i would not be eligible.

Comment: your separation form would say why you left the company.  If it says lack of work (or equivalent where you live), you are good.